# More zend framework2 routing issues

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I managed to figure out the basics of routing in zf2. Ive now hit a bit of a stumbling block as i need to route to different methods in my customers controller. Here's my attempt based on community answers :

```
 // Customers Routing
            'customers' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(

                    'route'   => '/api/customers[/]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Customers',
                        'action'        => 'index'
                    ),
                ),

                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array (
                    'add-product' => array(
                        'type' => 'method',
                        'options' => array(
                            'verb' => 'get',
                        ),
                        'child_routes' => array(
                            // actual route is a child of the method
                            'form' => array(
                                'may_terminate' => true,
                                'type' => 'Segment',
                                'options' => array(
                                    'route' => '/api/customers/[:id][/]',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Customers',
                                    'action' => 'all',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your question?

Your form child_route is available via the url `/api/customers/api/customers/[:id]` in this example, because parents-route is prepended.

Comment: Ahhh that's what I needed to know, I wasn't sure if I was putting the child route in the right place as I thought it was more like a best match system. Thanks